# Cover/block square Schluter Kerdi tile-in shower drain

Tags: shower, tile, drain

I'm looking to buy a [square Schluter Kerdi tile-in shower drain](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Shower-System/Drains/Schluter%C2%AE-KERDI-DRAIN/p/KERDI_DRAIN) for my current bathroom project. However, there are times when I would like to be able to plug this drain and allow some water to accumulate in the bottom of the shower.

I can't easily find any way to plug this square drain. Help?!

[image: square shower drain]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use a large flat [sink stopper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KOCA0WC)?

[image: sink stopper]

```
 Images and links for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: I've seen these, but I guess I've not been sure that they'd actually seal well to my oddly-shaped drain. I don't know how to test the seal without installing the drain, thus eliminating chances to send it back.

Comment: There are several types, some very thin that conform to the drain/sink.  Water pressure helps press them intot he base.  The biggest risk in your application (as opposed to a simple sink use) are the grout lines. They may make a tight seal and the associated water pressure a bit more problematic. Fuller grout lines would reduce the risk.